# How to properly configure my terraform folders for AWS deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

This is how my folder structure looks like

```
total 248
drwxrwxr-x 6 miki miki  4096 Mar  7 16:01 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 miki miki  4096 Mar  3 14:53 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki   460 Mar  4 11:59 application_01.tf
drwxrwxr-x 3 miki miki  4096 Mar  8 10:54 application-server/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki   862 Mar  4 09:06 ecr.tf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki  3169 Mar  4 11:36 iam.tf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki  1023 Mar  4 14:11 jenkins_01.tf
drwxrwxr-x 2 miki miki  4096 Mar  7 15:33 jenkins-config/
-rw------- 1 miki miki  3401 Mar  3 09:41 jenkins.key
-r-------- 1 miki miki   753 Mar  3 09:41 jenkins.pem
drwxrwxr-x 3 miki miki  4096 Mar  8 10:53 jenkins-server/
```

I run yesterday both `terraform init` and `terraform apply`
I found out that my application-server folder content is not implemented.
I have script file(update ,install docker,login to ECR, and pull image)

```
    sudo yum update -y
    sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
    sudo systemctl start docker
    sudo systemctl enable docker
/bin/sh -e -c 'echo $(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1) | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin ${repository_url}'
sudo docker pull ${repository_url}:release
sudo docker run -p 80:8000 ${repository_url}:release
```

Anyway I checked the instance from the console
[image]

I run

```
terraform plan
```

and this it says
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Your configuration already matches the changes detected above. If you'd like to update the Terraform state to match, create and apply a refresh-only plan:
terraform apply -refresh-only

My application.tf file

```
module "application-server" {
  source = "./application-server"

  ami-id = "ami-0742b4e673072066f" # AMI for an Amazon Linux instance for region: us-east-1

  iam-instance-profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.simple-web-app.id
  key-pair = aws_key_pair.simple-web-app-key.key_name
  name = "Simple Web App"
  device-index = 0
  network-interface-id = aws_network_interface.simple-web-app.id
  repository-url = aws_ecr_repository.simple-web-app.repository_url
}
```

And APPLICATION_SERVER folder

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki  417 Mar  2 11:18 application-server_main.tf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki  164 Mar  2 11:21 application-server_output.tf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki  398 Mar  2 11:17 application-server_variables.tf
drwxr-xr-x 3 miki miki 4096 Mar  8 10:54 .terraform/
-rw-r--r-- 1 miki miki 1076 Mar  8 10:54 .terraform.lock.hcl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki  866 Mar  4 14:39 user_data.sh
```

And application-server_main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "default" {
  ami = var.ami-id
  iam_instance_profile = var.iam-instance-profile
  instance_type = var.instance-type
  key_name = var.key-pair
  network_interface {
    device_index = var.device-index
    network_interface_id = var.network-interface-id
  }

  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/user_data.sh", {repository_url = var.repository-url})

  tags = {
    Name = var.name
  }
}
```

My scirpt is not executed. Why? How to structure properly Terraform across many folders?

Comment: Folders are modules - if you want to roll out stuff from a folder you need to reference it as `module "something" { source="path/to/folder" /* more config here */}` or not have it in a folder. Terraform only looks at top level tf files.

Comment: If that is a user data script, there is a way to add it to the EC2 instance resource.

Comment: @MarkoE Yes,but how? Something is wrong wit my configuration.

Comment: Obviously it is, based on your question. What is inside of the `application-server` module, can you add that to the question as well?

Comment: So `teraform apply` works as expected, without errors, but you can't see the software you want installed in the instance?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes,mow I destroyed everything and will try again.